# DateTime.TryParse not parsing simple date string C#

Tags: javascript, c#, datetime, cookies

I'm setting a cookie in Javascript where the value is the current date. I'm trying to check this value in my code, but `DateTime.TryParse("09/14/2017")`isn't working. This is my full code:

```
var cookie = Request.Cookies["DateCookie"];

if (cookie == null || String.IsNullOrEmpty(cookie.Value)) return false;

DateTime expiration;
if (DateTime.TryParse(cookie.Value, out expiration))
{
    if (expiration > DateTime.UtcNow) return true;
}
```

`cookie.Value = "09/17/2017";` this is being set by the following Javascript:

```
var d= new Date();
d= d.toLocaleDateString();
document.cookie = "DateCookie=" + d;
```

EDIT: I changed the line to

```
var date = cookie.Value

if (DateTime.TryParseExact(date, "MM/dd/yyyy", new CultureInfo("en-US"), DateTimeStyles.None, out expiration))
{ ...
}
```

and this still returns false

EDIT 2: When I saw DateTime.TryParse isn't working, I mean it is returning false when I expect it to return a valid date

Edit 3: I added this test code, and both cases are returning false. Why is this happening?

```
var testdate = "09/14/2017";
DateTime x;
var outcome = DateTime.TryParse(testdate, out x);
var outcome2 = DateTime.TryParseExact(date, "MM/dd/yyyy", new CultureInfo("en-US"), DateTimeStyles.None,
    out x);
```

Comment: Is working for me. Why do you say it's not working? What's your default culture?

Comment: I say it's not working because I step through my code and it does not return a value

Comment: What do you mean it doesn't return a value? If you have a non void function it has to return a value

Comment: For ever developers future sake please never inline your if statement

Comment: In C#, you can't not return a value if your method has a return type. So you must mean something else. Try to describe *exactly* what you see when you step through the code you provided in your quesiton, line by line.

Comment: it returns null. The outer if statement returns false

Comment: Are you saying your cookie is null?

Comment: Are you saying that `DateTime.TryParse("09/17/2017", out expiration)` returns false? If so, what is your default culture?

Comment: Yes. cookie.Value = "09/14/2017". I get to "if (DateTime.TryParse(cookie.Value, out expiration){   ...   }". This evaluates as false and continues past the if statement, so my function returns false. Meaning that DateTime.TryParse(cookie.Value, out expiration) is not parsing a valid date

Comment: I've changed this to if (DateTime.TryParseExact(date, "MM/dd/yyyy", new CultureInfo("en-US"), DateTimeStyles.None, out expiration))
                {
                    if (expiration > DateTime.UtcNow) return true;
                } so the culture is "en-US" and it still returns false

Comment: Are you confirming in the watch window that the cookie string is what you think it is? No, better yet: Try, just as a test, passing a literal string "09/17/2017" to TryParse and/or TryParseExact.

Comment: Yes. In the watch window the cookie string is "09/14/2017"

Comment: In your updated version of your code with TryParseExact, you're now passing a variable called `date`. What's `date`? Incidentally, this returns `true` for me: `DateTime.TryParseExact("09/17/2017", "MM/dd/yyyy", new CultureInfo("en-US"), DateTimeStyles.None, out expiration))`.

Comment: I added a new edit -- I tried putting in a hardcoded string of "09/14/2017", passing this into DateTime.TryParse and DateTime.TryParseExact with culture set to en-US and this still isn't working

Comment: OK, I found the problem. in TryParseExact I was passing in date, not testdate, and date was "9/14/2017" rather than "09/14/2017"

Comment: It's usually something like that.

Answer (score 1):

The Javascript that was setting the cookie returned a date string that did not have a leading 0 ("9/14/2017")

```
var d= new Date();
d= d.toLocaleDateString();
```

Therefore TryParseExacty with "MM/dd/yyyy" did not parse it. Fixed by adding a leading zero when the month < 10